# ChunkedEncodingError: ('Connection broken: IncompleteRead(8797 bytes read, 1443 more expected).Why is this happening?

Tags: python, python-requests, chunked-encoding

I am relatively new to python and I am currently working on python 2.7.x with a legacy project.
One of my requirement is to make an api request from code which I am doing through the requests.get method.
Whats weird is I get the exception every single time for the api when I try to invoke it.
Doing a curl or launching the api in browser works fine.
What could be the issue here?I cannot move to newer python versions as this is a legacy project I am working on.What can I possibly do to fix this?

my code is

```
import requests
url="http://<ip>:<port>/api/x.x/yz"
r=requests.get(url)
```

Comment: It's extremely difficult to say without any piece of relevant code

Comment: But connection error usually signifies problems with (internet) connection. Is this error persistent?